# Can Ordinal Regression be done on 2 likert scale variables

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data

I have 2 ordinal variables:

- Preferred Brand ranking 1 to 5 1 being Very Poor 5 being Very Good
- Preferred Country of Origin also ranking as above

Which test can I use to establish if the 2 variables are correlated? Is it possible for me to run Ordinal regression in SPSS?  If so which type of Ordinal regression?

Comment: Do you want regression or correlation?

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-are-good-basic-statistics-to-use-for-ordinal-data may help you.