# Standard deviation on a ten point scale

Tags: standard-deviation

Is there a way to calculate standard deviation on a semantic differential scale - 1(very dissatisfied) to 10 (delighted) scale? I have 100 respondents rating an attribute on this scale. How to calculate sd?

Comment: The formula doesn't change just because the scale might be limited or discrete: it's always the same.  Are you perhaps wondering whether the result might be meaningful?  Or how to interpret it?

Comment: Related: [What are good basic statistics to use for ordinal data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/97/), & [Under what conditions should Likert scales be used as ordinal or interval data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is not advisable to take the standard deviation of ordinal data although it is often done in practise. Depending on your needs perhaps a [frequency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_distribution) might summarise your data sufficiently?